# Creating Attendance Report with SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to create a Attendance result set in SQL Server for using it in a SSRS report. The `Employee Attendance` table is as below:

| EmpId | ADate | In | Out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 8:00 | 15:00 |

I need to calculate the Total working days for all months in a year and display the number of working days per employee. Report format should be as follows:

[image]

Saturday and Sunday being weekend, I can able to get the no of working days monthly.

Another table `tbl_Holiday` has entries for holidays `Fromdate` and `ToDate`. I need to consider that also when calculating working days. Several number of results i got from the internet for calculating this. But when creating a view using this data , it has to calculate workdays for each employee row

```
SELECT 
    EmpName, EmpId, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_EmpAttendance 
     WHERE EmpRecId = A.RecId 
     GROUP BY MONTH(Adate), YEAR(Adate)) AS WorkedDays,
    dbo.fn_GetWorkDays(DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(ADate), MONTH(ADate), 1), EOMONTH(ADate)) AS workingDays
FROM
    tbl_Employee A 
LEFT JOIN
    tbl_EmpAttendance B ON A.RecId = B.EmpRecId
```

`fn_GetWorkDays` - calculates the working days for month.

I need to get number of holidays from `tbl_holiday` too, I understand that this query is becoming more complex than I thought. There must be simpler way to achieve this, can anyone please help?

I tried to get the result in one single view, for using that as SSRS report dataset

Comment: Whitespace and Linebreaks are paramount to making readable text; not just in code. Please get into the habit of making good use of both. Poor/bad formatting is not going to help you or others when you need to be able to quickly read and understand your code. Using indentation and line breaks really helps easily distinguish specific code blocks and sections, and make finding errors far easier when a line only contains 10's of characters, rather than 100's.

Comment: Formatting your sample data is also important. DDL and DML is the *best* way to provide sample data, but otherwise you can use a markdown table.

Comment: Sorry i am new to stackoverflow. i am trying to change the format

Comment: Why not just create a WorkingYear table containing of all years between 2000 and 2050 and where you filter out sat/sundays/holidays and then just simply join against this table

Comment: Just create a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) - it will make all of these queries trivial. e.g. see "How many workdays are..." in [this follow-up article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6844/sql-server-calendar-table-example/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

Comment: Thanks, I need to consider weekends (set by user),holidays too. will try